# PHP registering to WWW-page

Tags: php

I'm doing a small forum on the web by PHP. I was wondering how to do the registration. Namely, I decided to ask user email and then sen her/him mail that contains a link that should be pressed at most two days after the server sent a mail. But it is possible for server to see what time the link was clicked? Or is there any better methods to do the registration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the link is clicked you can use php function date or time to log the current date.

If you also log the registration date, you can easily create a function which checks if the confirmdate is expired or if it's not.

This is an example how date comparison is done:

```
<?php
$date1 = "2007-10-25";

$date2 = time();
$dateArr = explode("-",$date1);

$date1Int = mktime(0,0,0,$dateArr[1],$dateArr[2],$dateArr[0]) ;

echo "$date1Int compare to $date2 difference is ".($date1Int-$date2);
?>
```

Comment: I would put the expiration date directly on the Database. There is two benefits. First, the SQL query will return nothing if (registration token do not exist or registration token expired). Second, a cron job will delete it, without knowing how much time a token should be valid.

Answer (score 1):

You can see which time the link was clicked using the [date](http://php.net/date) or [time](http://php.net/time) functions in PHP.

Comment: Okay. Now I have made my registration.php site such that it sends an email with registering link. Is it better to make the link to point the site registration.php or should I make a new registrationok.php page?